# Checkbox option in Rundeck

Tags: rundeck

I am creating a new job in rundeck, with the list of existing jobs under my project. But i don't know to have a checkbox option (linked with existing job), so that, user can make their selection and execute the required jobs in the displayed list.

Comment: Can you elaborate? Any example of your job (or job definition) may help.

Comment: Thank you for your response. For example, I have jobs as webserver1, webserver2, appserver1, appserver2. As mentioned in screenshot i can list the jobs, but how to link the existing jobs with the value/values. And, how to input parameters to each existing job, please explain.

Answer (score 0):

You can define a list and Set "Multi-valued" -> Yes with a delimitator (a comma for example). I leave a job definition example:

```xml
<joblist>
  <job>
    <context>
      <options preserveOrder='true'>
        <option delimiter=',' enforcedvalues='true' multivalued='true' name='mylist' value='one,two,three' values='one,two,three' valuesListDelimiter=',' />
      </options>
    </context>
    <defaultTab>nodes</defaultTab>
    <description></description>
    <executionEnabled>true</executionEnabled>
    <id>d75b11de-c272-402a-89cb-412e5f83e55f</id>
    <loglevel>INFO</loglevel>
    <name>Checkboxes</name>
    <nodeFilterEditable>false</nodeFilterEditable>
    <plugins />
    <scheduleEnabled>true</scheduleEnabled>
    <sequence keepgoing='false' strategy='node-first'>
      <command>
        <exec>echo ${option.mylist}</exec>
      </command>
    </sequence>
    <uuid>d75b11de-c272-402a-89cb-412e5f83e55f</uuid>
  </job>
</joblist>
```

With the [result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d4OKG.jpg).